# Laravel mix 5.4 сборка внешних пакетов

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

Устанавливаю несколько пакетов, в частности `socket.io`, `ioredis` (`npm socket.io` и т.д.). Вопрос: как правильно настроить webpack.mix.js, чтобы правильно использовать данные библиотеки? В простом примере

```
    var app = require('express')();
    var http = require('http').Server(app);
    var io = require('socket.io')(http);
    var Redis = require('ioredis');
    var fs  = require('fs');
```

которые вызываются в пользовательском js-файле. Здесь же проблема в require, которые, насколько я понимаю, нужно правильно задать перед сборкой и правильно вызвать (сейчас в браузере выдает `require is not defined`). Впервые работаю с вебпаками, поэтому заранее извиняюсь за такой примитивный вопрос или неясную формулировку. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

В `webpack.mix.js mix.scripts` надо было поменять на `mix.js`,сборщик сделал остальное